# 502 bad gateway while deploying stand alone webpack + react application on google cloud engine (no server)

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, webpack

I created a react application with webpack and am trying to deploy it to google app engine. There is no server to this application, everything is done in the browser. I have successfully deployed simple react apps previously but I think the webpack entry points is what is causing me headaches at the moment.

My application gets deployed successfully, but when navigating to the URL, I get a 502 bad gateway error. When looking at `$gcloud app logs read`, I see no issues, my app is compiled and built successfully, and none of the logs in the google cloud console are helpful either. I've tried moving all my devDependencies to dependencies.

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/env'
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|otf)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
        port: 8080,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

app.yaml:

```
# [START app_yaml]
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
# [END app_yaml]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "d3": "^5.11.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "d3": "^5.11.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all is properly set up, one of the possible causes is [scalability](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability). If it is not a scalability issue, do you have any support package/free trial? I'd recommend you to open a support ticket directly in the [support center](https://cloud.google.com/support/), if not you can contact Google through [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) as 5XX errors can be caused by different reasons, therefore very hard to troubleshoot from SO.